# What is the 'traffic thunder'?

Tags: meaning

Please let me know what 'traffic thunder' means!!!

Here is the whole sentence.

> On a bridge in the busy shopping district of Causeway Bay, a popular spot for pro-democracy protests over the past year, traffic thunders past fresh graffiti that says: “Arise, ye who refuse to be slaves.”

from [https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/jul/04/hidden-language-hong-kong-security-law-residents-wordplay]

Answer (score 2):

It's not parsed that way.

*Traffic* is a noun, and *thunders* is describing the manner in which the traffic passes.

> **thunder** *verb*
> 1.1 Make a loud, deep resounding noise.
> ‘the motorcycle thundered into life’
> [- Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/thunder)

Comment: oh... I can't understand why i thought that's the noun..ㅋㅋㅋ Thanks for your comment~~